# Will you write like "etc.)."?

Tags: punctuation, periods

Like say you a sentence like

> I like office apps (like word etc.)

Then how do you add period? Like `etc.).`? Will it be weird to have two dots so close and also like the U.S.A. at the end of the sentence we'll write like `I like the U.S.A.` which combine the dot and period together? Or this `etc.).` is the correct usage?

Answer (score 1):

It might look strange, but it requires both periods if it is inside parentheses.

From The Chicago Manual of Style (17th ed.), 6.13 (the bold text is mine):

> When an entire independent sentence is enclosed in parentheses or square brackets, the period belongs inside the closing parenthesis or bracket. When matter in parentheses or brackets, even a grammatically complete sentence, is included within another sentence, the period belongs outside . . . Avoid enclosing more than one complete sentence within another sentence. **In the third example, two periods are required—one for the abbreviation** ***etc.*** **and one for the sentence as a whole, outside the parentheses . . .**
>
> Fiorelli insisted on rewriting the paragraph. (His newfound ability to type was both a blessing and a curse.)
>
> Felipe had left an angry message for Isadora on the mantel (she noticed it while glancing in the mirror).
>
> His chilly demeanor gave him an affinity for the noble gases **(helium, neon, etc.).**